# How to merge grayscale and rgb image with opencv?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

These dont solve my questions :
[refs 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43442420/convert-merged-rgb-image-to-grayscale-opencv-android), [refs 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42920201/how-to-combine-a-rgb-image-with-a-grayed-image-in-opencv), [refs 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589012/combining-two-images-with-opencv/24522170)

Input 1 (Grayscale)[image: Input 1]

Input 2 (RGB)[image: Input 2]

Output [image: Output]

Question :
Is it possible to achieve both output with provided inputs? If yes, how to do it in python?

ps. dont mind the ball please. Its intended

Comment: Why does your Ref 2 not solve your problem? It seems to me that it does. Please [edit] your question to show what you’ve tried.

Comment: The refs2 combine image operation is placing input1 beside input2.

Comment: mask = grayImage>0; cv::cvtColor(grayImage, grayImage, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR; grayImage.copyTo(colorImage, mask);

Comment: @Micka I replace `copyTo` with `cv::bitwiseAnd` since theres no copyTo in python. Thats the same right?.
Whats the equivalent of `mask = gray > 0` in python. I got error `Expected cv::UMat for argument 'mask'`.

Comment: creating an image where every pixel that is not 0 in the imput image becomes 255 in the output image. biteise-and will not be the same, imho. What you want to do is copying all the pixels from gray image to color age, where the mask is 255 and don't change anything for the other pixels.

Comment: Okay, it solved my question. Thanks. :)
Please add brief explanation to answer section so it easier for others to visualize what happen and I can mark it as the answer.